# Number of Elements in a Conjugacy Class of $S_N$ (Derivation)

Tags: group-theory, permutations, binomial-coefficients, symmetric-groups

Consider the conjugacy classes of the symmetric group $S_N$. Each conjugacy class consists of permutations that have the same cycle structure. We see that the number of possible cycle structures is given by the number of ways of partitioning N.

For some permutation on N elements made up of $P_j$ $j$-cycles, it is trivial to see that:
$$
N = \sum_j j P_j
$$

Given some cycle structure, how can one calculate the number of elements, n, in the class pertaining to said structure?

Pierre Ramond's "Group Theory: A Physicist's Survey" gives this as:
$$
n = \frac{N!}{\prod_{j=1}^N j^{P_j} P_j!}
$$

Is this formula found by considering a binomial coefficient? I would very much appreciate it if someone could explain to me each term in this equation, specifically the denominator.

With Thanks, Sean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are at least two possible proofs, one of them by enumeration and
another one using the exponential formula.

By  enumeration, first  choose the  elements  to go  on each  cycle
(multinomial coefficient):

$$\frac{N!}{\prod_j (j!)^{P_j}}$$

Each of these elements generates $j!/j$ cycles (in placing labels on a
directed cycle  all orbits under the  action of the  cyclic group have
the same size which is $j$):

$$\prod_j \frac{(j!)^{P_j}}{j^{P_j}}$$

Permutations of the size $j$ cycles are not distinguished:

$$\prod_j \frac{1}{P_j!}.$$

This yields the answer

$$\frac{N!}{\prod_j (j!)^{P_j}}
\prod_j \frac{(j!)^{P_j}}{j^{P_j}}
\prod_j \frac{1}{P_j!}
= \frac{N!}{\prod_j j^{P_j} P_j!}.$$

The second proof uses the exponential formula (OGF of the cycle index
of the symmetric group)

$$Z(S_N) = [z^N] 
\exp\left(a_1 z + a_2 \frac{z^2}{2} + a_3 \frac{z^3}{3} + \cdots\right).$$

Extracting the coefficient of $[z^N a_1^{P_1} a_2^{P_2} \times\cdots]$
in $N! Z(S_N)$ we get

$$N! [z^N] [\prod_j a_j^{P_j}] \prod_j \exp\left(a_j\frac{z^j}{j}\right)
= N! [z^N] \prod_j \frac{z^{j P_j}}{j^{P_j} P_j!}
\\ = N! [z^N] z^{\sum_j jP_j} \prod_j \frac{1}{j^{P_j} P_j!}
= N! \prod_{j} \frac{1}{j^{P_j} P_j!},$$

the same as in the first version.  (Here we take $P_j = 0$ for a cycle
size that is absent.)

**Remark.** The reason for treating the  OGF like an EGF is that we
have the labeled species

$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}\textsc{SET}(
\mathcal{A_1}\textsc{CYC}_{=1}(\mathcal{Z})
+ \mathcal{A_2}\textsc{CYC}_{=2}(\mathcal{Z})
+ \mathcal{A_3}\textsc{CYC}_{=3}(\mathcal{Z})
+ \cdots)$$

and hence we are extracting from an EGF.

Comment: Could you explain the 2nd equation to me please, I'm not entirely sure where it comes from.

Comment: Given that you have $j$ distinct labels and want to build a directed cycle you can distribute these into the slots on the cycle in $j!$ ways. However cycles that can be obtained from one another by a rotation (cyclic group) are the same and should count as one. The orbits under this action all have the same size and contain $j$ assignments. Therefore, divide $j!$ by $j$ to get the answer.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks!